# Is it possible to have if condition with htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, if-statement

I would like to write simple if / else condition with .htaccess

Here is the code that is written in php.

```
if(isset($_GET['get'])){
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
}
```

is it possible to have same condition with htaccess

```
if(isset($_GET['get'])){
   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   </IfModule>
}
```

Comment: AFAIK you can't directly mix PHP into .htaccess like this. But .htaccess syntax has its own way to do an IF.

Comment: @LauriK this is only explanation to show what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can but with the .htaccess equivalents of your PHP code. You certainly can't invoke .htaccess code directly within PHP.

So, to conditionally set a header based on the presence of a query parameter you'll do something like

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)get=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [env=GET]

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=GET
```

Just make sure that ***mod_headers*** module is also loaded.

---

Please note that the above regex will pass if and only if `get` comes with some value. I believe PHP's `isset($_GET['get'])` would return `true` even if `get` is received *empty*. To match this behaviour you need to use `(^|&)get(=|&|$)` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer. But I could not run it with my development environment. From this address http://localhost/akasiayachting.com/?get=motoryachts&for=rent&sort=loa&by=asc&page=1&type=natural&perpage=15&theme=active-281&ref=http://localhost/akasiayachting.com/motoryacht-charter

What could be reason. Because I can echo $_GET['get'];